# openCSV CSVReader getRecordsRead method returns wrong count when used with iterator

Tags: java, opencsv

I am using opencsv version 4.1 (also tested with 4.2) for CSV reading.

Following is the test method written

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

CSVReader soruceReader = null; 

try {
    long recordCount = 0; 

    soruceReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("D:\\sample.csv"));
    recordCount = soruceReader.getRecordsRead(); 
    System.out.println("Records read : "+recordCount);

    Iterator<String[]> sourceIterator = soruceReader.iterator(); 

    recordCount = soruceReader.getRecordsRead(); 
    System.out.println("Records read : "+recordCount);

    boolean next = sourceIterator.hasNext(); 

    recordCount = soruceReader.getRecordsRead(); 
    System.out.println("Records read : "+recordCount);

    if (next) {
        String[] record = sourceIterator.next();

        System.out.println("Record red : "+record[0]+record[1]+record[2]+record[3]+record[4]);
        recordCount = soruceReader.getRecordsRead(); 
        System.out.println("Records read : "+recordCount);
    }

} finally {
    if (soruceReader != null) {
        soruceReader.close();
    }

}
```

}

and output is here -

```
Records read : 0
Records read : 1
Records read : 1
Record red : recordonthefirstline
Records read : 2
```

For the sample.csv File - which looks like -

```
record,on,the,first,line
record,on,the,second,line
record,on,the,third,line
```

It shows that iterator() method increments records read. I don't see any documentation which suggesting if/why it would do it nor does this seem logical.

Is this a bug with opencsv csvreader? or I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

The `getRecordsRead` method is intended for debugging purposes, according to the [documentation](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/CSVReader.html#getRecordsRead()).

The iterator is always reading in one record in advance in order to be able to provide the answer to `hasNext` queries.

Comment: Same getRecordsRead () method returns correct value when used with readNext() method. The issue is only when you attach an iterator().

Comment: I understand that. The `Iterator` internally likely reads one row before it is requested s.t. it can answer `hasNext` queries. Therefore, the counter is one too many if you use an `Iterator`. If you create two, the counter will be off be two. If you create none and only read via `readNext`, the counter will reflect how many rows you will actually have requested. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: I can confirm from the [source code](https://sourceforge.net/p/opencsv/source/ci/master/tree/src/main/java/com/opencsv/CSVIterator.java), that when `iterator()` is called, the `CSVReader`creates a `CSVIterator`, that immediately uses the CSVReader to read the first line, when initialized: `nextLine = reader.readNext();`
And the `hasNext` method simply returns the result of `nextLine != null;`

Comment: Ok. I chose to move away from using iterator and went back to readNext().